# LINQ and joining on selects

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join

I have the following SQL:

```
select  o.tekst as Enhet, 
        coalesce(f.Antall,0) as AntallF, 
        coalesce(f.snitt,0) as SnittF, 
        coalesce(b.antall,0) as AntallB 
        from tblhandlingsplan hp
    inner join tblorg o on hp.eierorgid = o.orgid
    left outer join (select f.handlingsplanid, count(t.tiltakid) as Antall, coalesce(avg(convert(float,t.status)),0) as Snitt from tblhandlingsplanforbedring f left outer join tblhandlingsplantiltak t on f.forbedringsid = t.forbedringsid group by f.handlingsplanid) f on hp.handlingsplanid = f.handlingsplanid
    left outer join (select b.handlingsplanid, count(b.bevaringsid) as Antall from     tblhandlingsplanbevaring b group by b.handlingsplanid) b on hp.handlingsplanid = b.handlingsplanid
where utsendingsid = 1
```

Which works exactly how I want it... Now I'm trying to convert this to LINQ...

I have gotten this far

```
from h in TblHandlingsplans
join o in TblOrgs
    on h.EierOrgID equals o.OrgID
join f in TblHandlingsplanForbedrings
    on h.HandlingsplanID equals f.HandlingsplanID into f2
join b in TblHandlingsplanBevarings
    on h.HandlingsplanID equals b.HandlingsplanID into b2
where h.UtsendingsID == 1
select new {
    Enhet = o.Tekst,
    AntallF = f2.Count(),
    AntallB = b2.Count()
}
```

however now I'm stuck... I can't for the life of me figure out how to include the average part from the SQL solution... Any takers?

I'm thinking of shoving the whole thing into a SP and leave it with that...

Comment: Can you create a dumbed down version of the SQL that just represents the part you can't figure out? I feel like there's a simple answer, but the question complicates it a bit with a bunch of tables we don't know much about.

Comment: The problem comes when i want to join on the "anonymous query" which gives me the count and average in the "tblHandlingsplanForbedring" table. If I didn't need the average, I would just have joined on the table directly, but I can't do that when I need the average value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query1 = from a in DB.Table1
             select new
             {
                 Id = a.Id,
                 Average = a.B.Average()
             };

var query2 = from b in DB.Table2
             join c in query1 on b.Id equals c.Id
             select c;
```

Just freehanded it, so it might not actually work, but is that the kind of thing you're trying to do? That would result in a single SQL query being created when query2 was used.